# R - How do I loop through several rows at once?

Tags: r, loops, imputation

For my thesis I have to impute values for several participants. I am using time-series data, and every participant has 297 rows and 18 columns (the variables). 
I want to impute values for each participant, so I have to perform the imputation method for every 297 rows. 
The rows are labeled with the participant ID (so 297 times 1 for the first participant. 
How do I loop through this huge dataset to perform the imputation per subject?

Thanks in advance!

Example data:

```
Participant ID  Var1 Var2
1               2.5  2.3
1               NA   2.5
1               2.2  2.4
1               2.6  2.5
2               2.2  2.2
2               2.3  2.4
2               NA   NA
2               NA   NA
```

In this example I used 4 rows per participant, but I have 297 rows per participant. I want to do my imputation method for every participant and for every variable seperately.

Comment: The [`mice`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/index.html) package was actually written for such purposes.

Comment: Could you maybe provide sample raw data and an example of how it should look like in the end?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already know my imputation method, I just have to find a way to select the participants from my dataset to apply the imputation method per participant.

Comment: check out group_by function from the dplyr package

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse)
library(Hmisc)
df %>% 
  group_by(Participant_ID) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-1), .funs = Hmisc::impute)
```

Comment: and inplace of Hmisc::imput you can also place your own imputation function that you have defined before

Comment: Thanks. Im having trouble installing and loading Hmisc. Updating my R now.

Comment: I have changed it into this: 
newData <-dataESM %>% 
  group_by(pid) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-1), .funs = na.kalman(dataESM[,8:24], model = "StructTS", smooth = TRUE)) 
It gives me the error: Not expecting this; call rlang::last_error() to see a backtrace. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work with the Hmisc::imput function or do you also get the same error there?
As the error message suggest you can call rlang::last_error() to see a backtrace of the error which might give you a hint why this error occurs. You can the backtrace with us aswell

Comment: try `mutate_at(vars(-1), .funs = na.kalman, model = "StructTS", smooth = TRUE)` or  `mutate_at(vars(-1), .funs = ~na.kalman(. , model = "StructTS", smooth = TRUE))`

Comment: Why are you using the . in the na.kalman function? If I leave the dot in, it gives me an error: Input data needs at least 3 non-NA data point for applying na.kalman

Comment: I still can't get it to work unfortunately. This is my code now:
 newData <- dataESM %>% group_by(pid) %>% mutate_at(.vars = list(c(8:24)),.funs=funs(na.kalman(dataESM, model = "StructTS", smooth = TRUE))) 
The whole dataset = dataESM. The participant id is stored in pid. I want to impute values in the 8th-24th column of the dataset with the na.kalman function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: thi is wrong `.funs=funs(na.kalman(dataESM, model = "StructTS", smooth = TRUE)))` see above.

Comment: If I change it to this: newData <- dataESM %>% group_by(pid) %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(c(8:24)), .funs = ~na.kalman(. , model = "StructTS", smooth = TRUE))    , I get the error:Input data needs at least 3 non-NA data point for applying na.kalman. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: The error says that some columns can't be imputed. You have to exclude them in the `vars(c(8:24))`

Comment: It works if I change it to 9:24. I found out that for one participant, variable 8 is missing completely, which causes the error. Thanks for your help!